# Getting the ID of currently logged in user in ASP.NET web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to get the ID and information of currently logged in user in ASP.NET web API. How can I get this information?

I am using ApiController.User property but user information is null. I am sending the request through Firefox REST client plugin.

Thanks

Comment: How's your application config? Did you set it to Windows or Forms authentication? Hows users authenticate to use the API?

Comment: @Fals: I am using windows authentication. I have added following in my app.config : <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
</system.web>

Comment: You should't provide windows authentication for Apis that will be acessed thorough Internet. Probably, your controller doen't have an AuthorizationAttibute, then the user Its null ever, everyone can access it without any credential.